# Block scope with "let" keyword

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, let

**Example 1**: the result is what I expected.

If we declare `let` inside of block, it shouldn't access from outside 
scope.

```
{
  let privateScope = 1;
  function thing() {
    privateScope = 2
  }
}
console.log(typeof privateScope); //undefined
```

**Example 2**: variable can be accessed outside scope!

```
{
  let privateScope = 1;
}
console.log(typeof privateScope); // number
```

Why can `privateScope` be accessed from outside the block in **Example 2**?

Comment: for me code #2 returns "undefined". what is execution environment?

Comment: doesn't do that here — anyway, `typeof` can certainly never return `1`, so perhaps something else is going on in your code

Comment: For me it also returns undefined. You are console.logging something else probably

Comment: Sorry, I mean it return "number" outside scope. (I edited the code). I run in https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Your engine probably doesn't fully support let declarations.

Comment: They don't run your exact code, they probably transpile it. You have to find out how and what code they actually produce.

Answer (score 3):

```js
{
  let privateScope = 1;
}
console.log(typeof privateScope);
```

Here's your example in an SO snippet with ES2015 checked. As you can see when you run it, `privateScope` is undefined. I can only assume StackBlitz is doing something odd when transpiling the code, or it's a configuration error.